# Dojo.grid.Datagrid row height in edit mode

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

In the dojo.grid.Datagrid, if the string is long, then it is transferred into multiple lines[pic 1]. When editing the row becomes one line[pic 2]. And the height of the row decreases.

How to make the height of row remained the same?

[image: "pic 1" - read mode, "pic 2" - edit mode]